How cheap is it to re-create and start `AudioBufferSourceNode`s?
MDN says:

An AudioBufferSourceNode can only be played once; after each call to start(), you have to create a new node if you want to play the same sound again. Fortunately, these nodes are very inexpensive to create, and the actual AudioBuffers can be reused for multiple plays of the sound.

The key word is “very inexpensive”.
Let’s say I have a substantial graph with 100 nodes, and some of them play samples at arbitrary frequency.
For specifics, let’s imagine there’s a dozen of nodes that play some half-second spans from various 1-minute-long audio buffers every beat at 120 BPM in this graph.

Is it sane to use the MDN-recommended approach—stop & disconnect node, create & connect & start a new node with the same buffer, on every beat for every such node?
It seems so far that re-creating & start()ing one or two nodes from the main thread is precise enough in terms of timing, musically speaking, though I’m yet to try it with many nodes.

Or, is it better to write a custom worklet (a la Nikku’s AudioSource)?
I suppose as a rule it’s always better to write a worklet, but would it yield significant enough improvements to warrant the effort?


